# how do I hide schema and migration information while running migration in adonisjs test

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, adonis.js

I am new to adonis JS. I have looked at the docs and other resources but couldn't figure out how to only show the test results without all the migration up and down information.

As you can see from image below, the result of test is sandwich between migration up and migration down information which I don't need.

Silent argument is passd to vowfile.js as well. This removes the list of migration files run. But doesn't hide other unnecessary information.

```
const ace = require('@adonisjs/ace')
await ace.call('migration:run', {}, { silent: true })
await ace.call('migration:reset', {}, { silent: true })
```

[image: Adonisjs test result]

Comment: Found workaround with using sqlite for testing.
```DB_CONNECTION=sqlite_testing```   

// config/database.js
sqlite_testing: {
    client: 'sqlite3',
    connection: ':memory:',
    useNullAsDefault: true
  },